# delete rows before data split into train set and test set

Tags: data-transformation

I have a dataset and due to some reasons,
I have to drop some rows because I have some nulls in some columns. and these null values cannot be replaced using imputation.
so I prefer delete rows with null values and then split dataset into train set and test set. is that right?
what if I should split dataset into train set and test set at first, and then delete rows but there is possibility that in the extreme I have to delete all rows of test set or the 90% of rows of test set.
Another problem bothers me would be that whether people should split data into train set and test set at the very beginning. Then we can dive into following process like discover and visualise the data to gain insights. In this way, we can avoid data peek in the visualisation.

Comment: If you are going to use cross validation, there is the possibility that you draw a split which contains mostly nulls, provided the split size is sufficiently small.  Dropping rows you aren't going to need prior to entering the pipeline is fine.

Comment: Thank for your answer!

Comment: @Demetri Pananos either way I would delete rows with nulls in some columns at last. since I know from the process of machine learning, first you should split data into train data and test data, then you start data exploration and data cleaning and modeling and so on(book: Hands-on machine learning with Scikit-learn& TensorFlow by Aurelien Geron Page 53).This is why I am confused.

Answer (score 2):

If you are confident that you have to delete the rows having NA values, then you should delete the NA first and then do the train/test split. The reason to do is to maintain coherency of the data.